# Formular una pregunta repetidas veces (Bucles en Python)

Tags: python

quiero que al seleccionar una opción me devuelva a la pregunta inicial para poder volver a ejecutar otra respuesta.

Quiero que al responder la pregunta con los comandos, me vuelva a preguntar lo mismo pero sin borrar la respuesta anterior.

```
comando = int( input("Que comando quieres usar? ") )
    
    if comando == 0:
        print("Hola")
    #Devolverme a la pregunta inicial
    
    elif comando == 1:
        print("Como estas? ")
    #Devolverme a la pregunta inicial
    
    else comando == 2:
        print("Adios")
```

Comment: Título = idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = detalles.

Answer (score 1):

Esta clase de preguntas no está recomendada en la comunidad.
Es un caso demasiado particular y seguro que existen ya respuestas que dan explicaciones más extensas de problemas similares.

Espero haber entendido bien tu frase *sin borrar la respuesta anterior*.

```py
# Historial de comandos introducidos
comando_hist = []
while True:
    # Pido el comando actual
    comando = int( input("Que comando quieres usar? ") )

    # Añado el comando al historial
    comando_hist.append(comando)

    if comando == 0:
        print("Hola")

    elif comando == 1:
        print("Como estas? ")

    elif comando == 2:
        print("Adios")
        # Salgo del bucle
        break
```

Déjame recomendarte que aprendas qué es una clase [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).
Es mucho más claro que usar números que no sabes qué significan.

Comment: @JoseLuis ¿Qué paquete en atom utilizas para ejecutar el código de python en atom?. ¿Qué paquete usas para poder ingresar datos en la ejecución del script? ¿Qué paquete usas para leer las entradas del usuario?

Comment: Esto que preguntas no está relacionado con tu pregunta original. ```input``` es una función de Python. Es la forma estándar de pedir información por teclado en las aplicaciones de consola. Respondiendo a tu pregunta: yo no uso atom.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar la pregunta las veces que quieras necesitas añadir un bucle while a tu código, éste bucle verificará la opción ingresada por el usuario y hará la pregunta inicial repetidamente hasta que la respuesta sea igual a 2. Tu puedes modificar hasta cuando quieres que el bucle se repita, en la condición del while.

```
comando = 0;

while comando!=2:
    comando = int( input("Que comando quieres usar? ") )
    if comando == 0:
        print("Hola")
    #Devolverme a la pregunta inicial
    elif comando == 1:
        print("Como estas? ")
    #Devolverme a la pregunta inicial
    elif comando == 2:
        print("Adios")
```